# Subwoofer still picking up signal from a powered down mixer

Tags: subwoofer

Subwoofer is powered on, conneceted to —> mixer through stereo and is off —> powered monitors are on.  I have an audio controller connected to monitors directly, and bass is still coming out of the subwoofer.  Have you ever heard of this happening before?  Its like the mixer is still sending a signal to subwoofer, or subwoofer is picking up a radio signal of the audio somehow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about sound design. It's an equipment routing/troubleshooting issue & should be referred to the relevant manufacturers.

Comment: Every question on here centres around sound equipment.  Disapointed to see the sound stack exchange is as unhelpful as the rest.  Is this site just for mongolian throat singers?

Comment: Actually, it used be be for the real experts; actual hollywood sound designers, top in their field. There was a major fall-out a long time ago when the stack was split into different parts, which many disagreed with. Subsequently, we're left with a myriad low-quality, barely on-topic questions, like "why does my mic input buzz?" Sad really, but that doesn't help your case.

Comment: You question is pretty much unanswerable anyway. "Has anyone else ever seen something like this?" I could honestly & truthfully answer, "Yes, back in the 80's I had a rack-mount compressor that with the power off became a quite interesting guitar fuzz box."…but that wouldn't help anyone. We don't know anything about your equipment. You'd be better off asking the manufacturer.